# What free software do you recommend for simple furniture visualization?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I'd like to make 3D visualization of a single piece of furniture with a white background, much like in the examples below:

[image]

What software, preferably free, would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SketchUp** => [LINK](https://www.sketchup.com)

It has a lot of libraries like 3D Warehouse, where you can build a furniture model with a few steps. Of course it has a "Pro" distro, but you wouldn't need it.

**Blender** => [LINK](https://www.blender.org)

This is a powerful free 3D tool, but you would need way more knowledge of modelling than with the SketchUp. Nevertheless, I recommend Blender because of his usage and very nice tools for rendering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think wil go for Blender. Can I use it in offline mode? Just don't want to save files in 'cloud'.

Comment: Yes, you can go offline:)

Comment: Fantastic. Marking it as useful answer. Have a great day Sylwester. Ps. since I don't have enough rep, I can just click the acceptance. :)

Comment: @Ramona if you need help with blender, ask at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

I will disent a bit with the accepted answer. Here is why:

There are several paradigms of 3D applications. Now blender is a DCC application. DCC applications are meant for generating mesh or subd models.

But manufacturing does not work with this constraint. Essentially the standard exchange formats of the manufacturing indusry works on boundary representation models.

So why should you care. Well, if you are making real chairs then this matters a great deal. Since you will find it nearly impossible to work woth other vendors. Maybe you want a hinge, or standard extrusion. Odds are these are available as step models that only really work in boundary representation models. Also if you have a vendor allready, they can provide step files. But usually provide totally unworkable meshes.

Its,a bit like choosing photoshop over indesign for making a book. Sure 
you can do it.

Now, these dont come in free form except maybe free cad. I would suggest you use Fusion 360, inless you can afford something better like solidworks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Just to be honest with you I dont understand much of it because I'm just not that familiar with these programs. I've instaled this Blender and it works fine (I guess). The issue in my case is that I have the actual photos of this furniture but just want to make it look like these in the link I provided above. Would Fusion 360 do the job?

Comment: @Ramona sure.  Most likely somebody has a model of the chair somewhere, even if its just a 2D drawing. Procuring those might be worthwile. Anyway be prepared to put some hours whatever approach  you choose learning 3D is challenging.

Comment: Oh yes. It's way different than my beloved Illustrator :) So now I have three choices - Blender, SketchUp or Fusion 360. Which one would you recommend? :) PS. Is this Blender actually free or not?

Comment: Then definitely a indirect mechanical cad like fusion for you. Anyway, how long did it take for you to be productive in illustrator? Triple that to get productive in a 3D app.

Comment: No way! You serious? :)  So it means over a year for me to learn.. :) But so far I just want to make visualization like in this link from my first post. Hopefully it will take not that much  time cos my furniture (table) isnt that complicated :) Sending only a picture to this vendor wont be a good idea. I just wanna look more like a pro ;) But what will be the final outcome? ..who nows :)

Comment: @Ramona yes that is about right. But really you should be just sending them technical drawings not a 3D render. (please note that it took me about 12 hours to learn illustrator, otoh it took me a year to learn Maya, 3 months Creo/ProE)

Comment: Yes, Illustrator is quite easy.. See, in my case I have this product ready and some pics of it are taken too. But instead of sending many pics I just want to do this 3D model for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80392/discussion-between-joojaa-and-ramona).

Answer (score 0):

SolidWorks is a very simple and straight to the topic furniture design software. It's supporting a wide variety of materials.

You can use this tool to design virtually any type of furniture components, including desks, chairs, tables, office panels, and customize them according to your needs.

More info about 3d modeling software: https://windowsreport.com/furniture-design-software/

Comment: Is it free? OP said that he need free software and SolidWorks is expensive as far as I know.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a free version available? Can't find.

Comment: @Ramona sure free versions exist for all students. But if your not a student then no dice.

Comment: Im not :( way older :) Fusion 36,  Blender or SketchUp left.

Answer (score 0):

There are many. Almost any software that you can render a 3D model with will do.
I'd say if you never used 3D before Sketchup has a less steep learning curve.

Comment: I guess you are right. Any opinion on Fusion360 which @JoJaa mentioned.